# Virtual inheritance ambiguous function

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have this part of code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
int i;
    A(){i = 0; }
    virtual void f() { cout << i; }
};
class B1 : virtual public A {
public:
    B1() { f(); }
    void f() { cout << i+10; }
};
class B2 : virtual public  A {
public:
    B2() { f(); }
    void f() { cout << i+1; }
};
class C : public B1, public B2 {
public:
    C() {}
};
void main(){
    C c;
    //c.A::f();
}
```

First, I understand the main idea behind using virtual inheritance (diamond) in order to create only one `A` object in memory.

In this example, I get compilation error in `C` class:

```
override of virtual function "A::f" is ambiguous
```

If I remove the `virtual` inheritance. The code compiles, there is no error in class `C` as before.

If I remove the comment from the last code line it still compiles. I understand that in this case the `f()` function that will be executed is the one from the first class that `C` inherits from.

Now, if I replace `c.A::f()` with `c.f()` I get a compilation error at this specific line.

Can someone please explain this behaviour and the differences between these cases?

Comment: Who said off-topic??? This is just duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `C` not with your expression call. As `f` is virtual and redefined twice in `B1` and `B2` then the `C` class is malformed because a call to `f`would be ambiguous (which override to choose?). Add an override of `f` in `C`and everything will be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Within the class C you must choose which variant of f to usr. That is, `using B1::f;` or `using B2::f`.

Comment: I know how to make it work, but I am trying to understand the concept and reasons for this behaviour.

Comment: The reason is it sees two conflicting definitions in the two base classes and it doesn't know which. My solution says which one you want it to use.